# What's the name of the curves obtained by intersecting a n-holed torus and a plane?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-curves, elliptic-curves, curves, elliptic-functions

[Cassini ovals](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CassiniOvals.html) are a well-known family of quartic curves which include the [lemniscate](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Lemniscate.html) as a special case. They can be thought as the vertical cross sections of a torus, that is, the intersections of a torus and a plane (picture taken from Tristan Needham's *Visual Complex Analysis*):

[image]

Is there a name for the family of curves obtained by intersecting a n-holed torus and a plane in a similar fashion? By n-holed torus I mean the connected sum of n tori, where n is any natural number:

[image: A n-holed torus]

The reason I'm asking is that such curves seem to appear in the [phase portrait of a pendulum](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~feldman/m428/phaseplane.pdf), and I was curious to know more about them:

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid $n$-holed tori don't have standard Euclidean embeddings. Without such, one cannot make much sense out of your question.

Comment: @Wojowu Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. One should be able to take the cross sections of, say, a 2-fold torus. That would give a family of curves, and I'm just asking if those curves have a name.

Comment: Let me ask the following question: how do you define, precisely, $n$-holed  torus?

Comment: @Wojowu I was thinking of the connected sum of n tori, where n is any natural number, but I'm afraid I don't know a more precise definition. For instance, for n=3: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ac/Triple_torus_array.png

Comment: The problem is, just specifying that you take the connected sum doesn't, in a way, specify a $2$-holed torus as a subset of $\mathbb R^3$. But we need such a subset in order to speak of the intersection of it with a plane.

Comment: @Wojowu Well, I think I can see your point (apologies if the question was unclear), but I don't know what further specifications could I give. Perhaps I should have asked directly for the name of the curves in the phase portrait.

Comment: 1) A little precision "They can be thought as the **vertical** cross sections of a torus" 2) The curves that are pictured in the phase portrait are linked to **elliptical functions**. See (http://www.phy.ilstu.edu/~rfm/380s13/chapters/CH2.2_Pendulum.pdf).

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you very much!

Comment: A very interesting and recent reference (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1308.3569) "Bose-Hubbard dimers, Viviani's window and pendulum dynamics"  by Graefe, Korsch and Strzys.

Comment: @JeanMarie Wow, that looks truly interesting! I'll need to read it carefully. Are those Viviani curves related to Cassini ovals by (something like) stereographic projection?